# Wifi network channel width

Tags: wifi, ieee, wlanapi

I try to get the channel width of networks so I'm using [WlanGetNetworkBssList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlangetnetworkbsslist) to retrieve a list of BSS entries of the wireless networks on a wireless LAN interface but I don't see any information about the channel width. It's kinda trivial to get the channel center frequency to obtain the number of used channel and many other information but the channel width seems to be an obscure information stored somewhere in IE data blob of BSS entry structure. I managed to get some information about the width of the channel from HT and VHT Operation information elements but doesn't seem to be enough. I found on Github a [python wrapper](https://github.com/opetryna/win32wifi/commit/35bc65df12ae8e3c579f4e867b3bfcadfb6e072a) that extract info from Extension information element but it's not clear from which one since IE data blob of BSS entry structure might have more IE Extension elements.

For example I have 5 different IE Extension elements:

```
FF 1A 230108080E00580C2F4EC96FC927DE018F00FAFFFAFFFAFFFAFF
FF 07 24E43F003CFCFF
FF 03 272500
FF 0E 260600FFFF20FFFF40FFFF60FFFF
FF 02 252A
```

I found some basic information about [HT Operation](https://mrncciew.com/2014/11/04/cwap-ht-operations-ie/) and [VHT Operation](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/80211ac-a-survival/9781449357702/ch03.html) information elements but nothing about Extension information element.

Where I can find the specifications for these information elements of AP beacon frames?